# Select Option dropdown taking time to close specifically in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have two select option buttons on single web page but on different tabs. I want to change the other one button value on change of any one button and assign it to some element like span in example code. All things are working perfectly but it just taking time to close dropdown when i am changing value. in firefox there is no problem

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r69jrywn/1/)

My HTML Code

```
<select class="select one" >
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select><br><br><br>
<select class="select two">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<br><br><br>
 <span class="value"></span>
```

JQuery

```
var lang =  $('select.one').val();
$('span.value').text(lang);

$('select.select').change(function(){
            lang = $(this).val();
            $('span.value').text(lang);
            if ($(this).hasClass('one')) {
                    $('.two').val($(this).val()).trigger('change'); 
            }
            else{
                $('.one').val($(this).val()).trigger('change'); 
                }

        });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: FF lags also a bit...

Comment: Thanks :) Roko C. Buljan and Jai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[fixed jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/r69jrywn/4/)***

It's cause you're concurrently triggering changes. Cool that down, this is all you need:

```
var lang = $('select.one').val();
$('span.value').text(lang);

$('select.select').change(function () {
  lang = this.value;
  $('span.value').text(lang);
  $('.select').val(lang);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead:

```
var lang = $('.select.one').val();
$('.value').text(lang);

$('.select').change(function (e) {
    $('.select').val(this.value);
    $('.value').text(this.value);
});
```

---

The issue was `.trigger()` method, that was traversing up to the dom for lookup and setting the values to each elem again and again.

#### [Check the updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/r69jrywn/6/)

Comment: Also `$('.one').val(this.value); lang = this.value;` the order and the way you're setting the `lang` value makes no sense... :) Sorry just noticing

Comment: yeah! yours is better.

Comment: OK Jai, now after your (good) edit, your answer (apart the *not-stored-in-variable* `this.value`) is (quite) exact as mine. Which is a bit embarrassing ...and funny at the same time :)

Answer (score 0):

I spent 8 hours dealing with a simple HTML selection option in react. It was like there was a 1 second forced delay in any operation on the select. I updated chrome and it was solved, didn't happen in firefox.

I think chrome auto-installs updates and just sits there in a stupid state until the browser is restarted, the first brains to go seem to be the select operation. I think I've seen this condition before in chrome, but its rare.